# Image Upload receiving response as "The server cannot service the request because the media type is unsupported"

Tags: android, httpclient, image-upload

I am trying to upload an image from my android application on the server through a wcf webservice method. It is throwing me an error as "***The server cannot service the request because the media type is unsupported***".

The code used to upload the image is as below :

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://myWebServicelink/Service1.svc/UploadFile/");
              ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(sendData,fileName);

MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);


              reqEntity.addPart("f", bab);
              reqEntity.addPart("fileName", new StringBody(fileName));
              postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
            HttpResponse response=  httpClient.execute(postRequest);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            String result= EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

The UploadFile method accepts two parameters as `string UploadFile(byte[] f, string fileName);`

and returns a string as "OK" if the image is transferred or throws an error if not.

The webservice method is as follows :

```
  public string UploadFile(byte[] f, string fileName)
    {
        // the byte array argument contains the content of the file
        // the string argument contains the name and extension
        // of the file passed in the byte array
        try
        {
            // instance a memory stream and pass the
            // byte array to its constructor
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(f);

            // instance a filestream pointing to the 
            // storage folder, use the original file name
            // to name the resulting file
            FileStream fs = new FileStream
                (System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/TransientStorage/") +
                fileName, FileMode.Create);

            // write the memory stream containing the original
            // file as a byte array to the filestream
            ms.WriteTo(fs);

            // clean up
            ms.Close();
            fs.Close();
            fs.Dispose();

            // return OK if we made it this far
            return "OK";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // return the error message if the operation fails
            return ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Why is it throwing this error, i am able to figure out. What am i missing here ? 
 Please help.

Comment: Maybe this post is helpfull:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798837/android-sending-image-to-server-via-multipartentity-setting-content-type

Comment: Looks like you haven't set the content-type header. The server won't know unless you set that.

Comment: @LachlanEnnis i tried setting the content type header as `postRequest.setHeader("Content-Type:", "image/jpeg");` but this too was not yielding any response. What content type should i set??

Comment: Check this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404067/send-an-image-from-android-to-an-asp-net-web-service

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617857/soapfault-exception-http-unsupported-media-type-when-accessing-java-web-servi